# Resources (books, etc) to learn about concurrency theory

Tags: lambda-calculus, concurrency, process-algebra, petri-nets

I want to know more about concurrency theory from a formal/mathematical point of view, I know there are a lot of computer science branches that relates to concurrency theory like [process algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_calculus), [Petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net), [Actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model_theory), [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes), etc.

But I don't know about classic books on that topics, and also I would like to know in which order it's better to study, I'm new to this field, I have some basic knowledge on λ-calculus and Turing machines theory.

What resources do you recommend to begin with this theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are not that many books on this subject, as it continues to evolve at a rapid pace.

Classic books on process calculi (that don't focus on π-calculus-like mobility) are:

- C. A. R. Hoare, [Communicating Sequential Processes](http://www.usingcsp.com/cspbook.pdf).
- A. W. Roscoe, [The Theory and Practice of Concurrency](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/bill.roscoe/publications/68b.pdf).
- M. C. B. Hennessy, Algebraic Theory of Processes.
- R. Milner, Concurrency and Communication.

There are two main books on π-calculus:

- R. Milner, [Communicating and Mobile Systems: The Pi Calculus](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/computer-science/communications-information-theory-and-security/communicating-and-mobile-systems-pi-calculus?format=PB&isbn=9780521658690).
- D. Sangiorgi, D. Walker, [The Pi-Calculus: A Theory of Mobile Processes](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/pi-calculus-theory-mobile-processes?format=PB&isbn=9780521543279).

The Sangiorgi/Walker book is not easy reading. The others books above can be used by a learner.

All of the books above are (mostly) about untyped processes. There is a single book on types for interactive processes (from June 2017).

- S. Gay, A. Ravara, [Behavioural Types: from Theory to Tools](http://www.riverpublishers.com/research_details.php?book_id=439).

Regarding recommendations, that would depend on your background and specific goals. The Milner and Hoare books should be easy to access. After those you can read the original papers.